# C# making tiles in grid class swap

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a slider puzzle game where the tiles swap positions and to win, the tiles need to be in order from 1 to 8. So the winning layout looks like this,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6          
7 8 (b)

b = blank tile
```

It is in a 3 by 3 grid with the numbers 1, 2, and 3 on top column and 7, 8, blank on last column.

The numbers are in an imagelist and the imagelist is in a grid in boundedgrid class. The form1 appears as above. I want it so that is u click on tile 6 or tile 8, it will swap tiles with the blank tile. My question was what event do I need to swap tiles in the picturebox? Is it mouseclick...mousedown?

Answer (score 1):

`MouseDown`, `MouseClick`, `MouseUp`, I think either can do. If you want the swapping begins after mouse is released, then use `MouseUp` event, the benefit is if user presses the mouse button on the `PictureBox` but he is not so sure, he can still move the mouse out of the `PictureBox` before releasing the button, so the `MouseUp` event will not be fired.

Comment: Of course the downside is a sloppy clicker could be down on the edge of tile 1, slide a bit in the process, and be up on 2.  That would look like a program error to the user.  Binary state clicks are sometimes best handled in `MouseDown` to capture quickly and cleanly.